# Send data from controller to directive

Tags: angularjs, directive

I want to send that to my directive but I want that data to stay updated if the data in the controller changes.

```
// Controller
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('IndexController', IndexController)

IndexController.$inject = [];
function IndexController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.name = 'John';

    newName = function() {
        vm.name = 'Brian';
    }
    newName();

}

// Directive
angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('userName', userName);

userName.$inject = ['$document'];

function userName($document) {

    var directive = {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div id="user"></div>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            name: '='
        },

        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.data);
        }
    }
    return directive;
}
```

this is how I use the directive. the problem is that it always returns the first name and not the new name after the change in the controller.

```
<div ng-controller="indexController">
    <user-name name="indexController.name">
</div>
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you just have to inject `$scope` into your `Indexcontroller`

```js
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('IndexController', function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.name = 'John';

    vm.newName = function() {
        vm.name = 'Brian';
        console.log(vm.name);
    }
    //vm.newName();

})
 .directive('userName', ['$document', function() {

    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div id="user"></div>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            name: '='
        },

        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.name);
        }
    }
    return directive;
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="IndexController as vm">

<user-name name="vm.name"></user-name>
  <button ng-click="vm.newName()">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. this works perfectly. I guess I'm still really confused with $scope, vm and this

Comment: OK.. it works only in the given scenario. but if I have a <button ng-click="vm.newName()">click</button> it doesn´t work. what else is missing? thank you!

Comment: You don't have to change anything.I just updated above answer which works with ng-click.

Answer (score 0):

> Without using `as` in controller, you cannot use `controller.prop` inside the scope.
>
> Inside the controlleryou need to call the method using its `$scope` or `this`.

- Check the below code.

```js
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('IndexController', function($scope) {
    
    $scope.name = 'John';

    $scope.newName = function() {
        $scope.name = 'Brian';
    }
    $scope.newName();

})
 .directive('userName', ['$document', function() {

    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div id="user"></div>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            name: '='
        },

        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.name);
        }
    }
    return directive;
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="IndexController">

<user-name name="name"></user-name>
</div>
```